# THREE.js Upload Cell Fracture Blender Animation

Tags: javascript, animation, three.js, blender

I have just finished a small blender animation where a cube fractures (using cell fracture) and then reforms by putting the animation in reverse.

The following is an example of what I am referring to:

[image]

In my version of the previous example, I have put a material on all of the fractured objects. However, when I use the three.js exporter for blender 2.73 the only code I get in the JSON file is the following:

```
{
"data":{
    "attributes":{
        "position":{
            "array":[-1,2.75745,0.498738,-0.50101,2.75716,0.499237,-1,3.25606,0.498823,-0.501269,3.25664,0.498822,-0.500632,3.25664,-0.408387,-1,2.75718,-0.40865,-0.501298,2.75765,-0.498682,-1,3.25664,-0.498807,-0.500658,3.25664,-0.498588,-1,2.75723,-0.499097],
            "type":"Float32Array",
            "itemSize":3
        }
    },
    "index":{
        "array":[0,1,2,3,1,4,1,0,5,4,1,6,6,1,5,1,3,2,2,7,5,7,8,6,7,2,4,8,4,6,9,6,5,5,0,2,7,9,5,9,7,6,4,8,7,2,3,4],
        "type":"Uint16Array",
        "itemSize":1
    }
},
"metadata":{
    "version":3,
    "type":"BufferGeometry",
    "generator":"io_three",
    "position":10
}
}
```

Please let me know what I can do to properly export this kind of animation to Three.js. There are only 25 fractions of the cube in my version. Any and all help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default settings for the thrre.js exporter will only export the one active object.

When you export, on the left there are options available to adjust the export. You will find one that should enable exporting the whole scene.

[image: scene export option]

Comment: Thank you! Hopefully this works. Do you have any code you can suggest to me to load said animated JSON scene? I am looking to animate on click and I've been having trouble finding solid code for loading JSON animated scene.

Comment: I don't use three.js so can't help there.